# How do I handle errors properly with fast CSV?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, fast-csv

In the code below, I want to check if the headers are valid and then stop reading the stream if they are and send an error back to the client (via my ErrorHandler function). I see the following in my console:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Please check your column headers.

Why is that?

```
uploadExercisesViaFile = async (
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) => {
    try {
      let checker = (arr, target) => target.every((v) => arr.includes(v));
      const columns = ["name", "link", "description"];

      const results = [];
      let errors: string[] = [];
      const parseCSV = parseString(req.file.buffer.toString(), {
        headers: true,
        maxRows: 5,
      })
        .on("headers", (header) => {
          if (!checker(header, columns)) {
            errors.push("Please check your column headers.");
            parseCSV.end();
          }
        })
        .on("data", async (row) => {
          console.log(row);
          results.push(row);
        })
        .on("error", (error) => {
          errors.push(error.message);
        })
        .on("end", async (rowCount) => {
          // Check if errors
          if (errors.length > 0) {
            console.log(errors);
            throw new ErrorHandler(400, errors[0]);
          }

          // Upload
          const uploadedExercises = await Exercises.batchUploadExercise(
            results.map((r) => {
              return { ...r, access: req.body.access, coach: req.user.id };
            })
          );
          res.status(200).json({ rowCount: rowCount });
          return;
        });
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  };
```